# How to change TextView in fragment in on create or when a button is called

Tags: onclick, textview, fragment, settext, textedit

Almost 10 hours am I searching for an answer. Why my app crashes when i launch it.

What I realy want is a function that when I click OK on Edittext, text will be written on Text view. But first just hat to set text in on create in class that extence fragment.

```
package youtube.demo.youtubedemo.Fragments.Calculator_list;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import youtube.demo.youtubedemo.R;
public class Calculator_list extends Fragment  {
View view;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public Calculator_list() {
}
TextView Damage1pise;
    EditText Damage1beri;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator_list, container, false);
     Damage1beri = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Game1_read_dmg_list_Player1);
        Damage1pise = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Game1_writen_dmg_list_Player1);
        Damage1pise.setText("123");
        return view;
    }
    public TextView Returnelement ()
    {
        return  Damage1pise;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Damage1pise = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.Game1_writen_dmg_list_Player1);
        Damage1pise.setText("1234");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

What I realy want is a funcction that when I click OK on Edittext, text will be written on Text view

```
public void OnButton1click(View v)
{
  Damage1.settext(v.text)    

 // This is hard coded, First I want to set text on create then go on whit the code



}
```

Here are the errors.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: youtube.demo.youtubedemo, PID: 2736
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                      at youtube.demo.youtubedemo.Fragments.Calculator_list.Calculator_list.onCreate(Calculator_list.java:47)
                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2335)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:857)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:897)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:727)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Please, show the logcat errors for us.

Comment: When I open the fregment it crashes, somewhere here.


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Damage1pise = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.Game1_writen_dmg_list_Player1);
        Damage1pise.setText("1234");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

Errors

Answer (score 0):

On this line of your showed code, both methods, certify yourself you have a **blank space** between `(TextView)` and the end of the sentence, like below:

`Damage1pise = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.Game1_writen_dmg_list_Player1);`

Also, certify yourself you have a textview on your invoked layout file **xml** with name **Game1_writen_dmg_list_Player1**, because the error is been raised by a null reference, i.e.: you're invoking a not found element (maybe **written** with two **t**s?).

Comment: @Jaka Basej excuse me, can I help in something more? Thank you.

Comment: @Jaka Basej please, have you found your problem? It was that thing I pointed to you after an analysis? If so, please, recognize my efforts in your benefit. Thank you.